# Can't retrieve urlencoded umlauts. [solution: use UTF8]

Tags: java, jsp, webforms, urlencode, diacritics

I'm programming some websites with JSP-Scripting and I encounterd a strange problem with urlencoded web-formular parameters. The site itself is encoded in iso-8859-1.

I have a simple webform with a field called `description`.

If I enter german Umlauts or specialchars like "ü" or "ß", these get automatically urlencoded. But if I want to read this parameter, I always get `null`.

```
String description = request.getParameter("description");
```

If I enter some chinese words, like `專業人士`, they are urlencoded, too. However, I can read them without retrieving `null`.

This behaviour doesn't change whether I use "post" or "get" as method.
I tried to "pimp" my webform with the text below - but that didn't help either.

```
accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

My question is:
Why can't I retrieve urlencoded german Umlauts but some chinese words?

Comment: description is always the hard coded string "description" ?

Comment: Yes, it's always the same string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chinese with ISO-8859-1 wont't work, but german should. If chineese is encoded anyway, maybe your form is encoded in UTF-8? Which browser so you use? What is the encopding of the JSP? You should always use UFT-8, not Latin 1. Nowadays every browser and server should support UTF-8 on every OS.

My experience is, that GET ist often not working with encoding, but POST should do. The form parameters accept-charset and enctype are correct. What server do you use?

The JSP content type is typically set by:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
                         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
```

Comment: I know that Latin 1 is "outdated" - but I'm stuck to some legacy systems.. I can switch to UFT-8, but that's not that easy.

The encoding of the file itself, the meta-tag, and the page-directives are all set to iso-8859-1.

    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    %>

Browser: Firefox, IE 6, Safari, Opera .. what you want
Server: IIS + Resin (Java EE Server from caucho.com)

GET for this form was only for testing. I prefer POST, too.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do not set the encoding on the request or response in that way. Just the contentType on the page.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that tomorrow.

Why is it better to set these encoding via the page-directive?

Comment: Ok, it was a strange behaviour with IE6. It simply doesn't send the data ...
I'm using now UTF-8 and everythings works like a charm ...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your page or servlet encoding is UTF-8. The Latin-1 encoded Umlaut is an invalid UTF-8 sequence so you get NULL.

When you enter Chinese, the browser knows it can't encode this in Latin-1 so it changes into UTF-8 automatically. That's why Chinese works.

If you can post some HTTP trace, we can confirm this.